# Can the Pythagorean Theorem be extended like this?

Tags: pythagorean-triples

What is the significance, if any, of the fact that

$3^3$ + $4^3$ + $5^3$ = $6^3$

?

How curious this is. This would be like the Pythagorean Theorem exploding into a higher dimension, on steroids.

Comment: What geometry is this meant to reflect?

Comment: Looks like the $\ell^3$ norm.

Comment: No particular geometry.  I was just struck when I came across this.

Answer (score 1):

This is, in fact, the analogous expression to the distance between two points $x$ and $y$ in the space $\Bbb{R}^4$. However, the "euclidean" (or "pythagorean") distance in $n$ dimensions is given by:
$$\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^{n} (x_i - y_i)^2} $$
There is a generalization, called Minkowski distance:
$$\Big({\sum_{i=0}^{n} |x_i - y_i|^{1/p}}\Big)^p$$
And you recognise here your expression with $p=1/3$.

In conclusion, this is an integer expression for the distance between two points in $\Bbb{R}^4$, with the $1/3$-Minkowski metric.